# How to identify class in minified Google Closure code?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

Using Google Closure inheritance paradigm how can I see whats the class name or how can I otherwise identify the class since `object.constructor.name` returns `""` and is incorrect when minified?

The purpose is to execute code dependent on the implementation of an interface or inherited class. This code is inside of a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) class which extends `Animal`, too:

```
var object = XXX; // of @type {Animal}
switch (object.constructor.name) {
    case 'Dog':
       //...
       break;
    case 'Cat':
       //...
       break;
}
```

Comment: My current solution is to add my own "identifier" to each class.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will also work:

```
switch (object.constructor) {
case Dog:
  ...
case Cat:
  ...
}
```

or (a little uglier since you can't use `switch`)

```
if (object instanceof Dog) {
  ...
} else if (object instanceof Cat) {
  ...
} else if ...
```